# Sum of $P(k^3+1)$ modulo $10^9+7$

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

$P(N)$ represents the largest prime factor of $N$.

Find the sum of $P(k^3+1)$ for $1≤k≤107$ modulo $10^9+7$

Comment: The modulo part doesn't change anything, since $P(k^3+1)=\max(P(k^2-k+1),P(k+1))\leq k^2-k+1$ for $k>1$, so the sum is less than $10^9+7.$ Or did you mean $1\leq k\leq 10^7$?

Comment: Modulo $10^9+7$??!!!?? Looks like something Project Euler would use. Are you sure you are not trying to cheat in one of their contests?